# How to secure replacment?

Tags: lua

So I need to secure my code.
My code is obfuscated and im using `load(tostring(resultServerr))()` but someone can do load = print on top and it will print everything from my code..
I have to secure it to avoid replacement but i dont know how.

Comment: If you're not in control of the machine thats executing the code, you can't

Comment: What stops someone from, not only doing `load = print`, but just opening the code file, deleting the word `load`, and adding the word `print`?

Comment: They cant open it and edit because it is obfuscated so only way is to add load = print on top code.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Lua 5.2 or higher, you can provide your own sandboxed _ENV table [in 4th argument of `load`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-load). If you use Lua 5.1 or 5.0 you can use [`setfenv`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-setfenv), which works almost the same way as new _ENV.

```lua
local func, err = load(unsafecode, nil, nil, {})
if not func then print(err) return end
func()
```

or

```lua
local func, err = load(unsafecode)
if not func then print(err) return end
setfenv(func, {})
func()
```

Here I use empty table `{}` to protect from using all globals, adding new ones and overwriting existing. If you want to provide some functions, just add them into this table, they won't be removed from _G if they change it inside the sandboxed code.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how and where are you using lua environment and what normal user is allowed to do with lua?

If **only you controls startup process** of the server or programm and the **user has no access** to startup process, it is possible to do sandboxing on init state as suggested Spar, or something like:

init.lua:

```lua
function prepare()
  local load = _G.load
  _G.load_extension = function()
    local obfuscated = get_extension()
    load(obfuscated)
  end
end
```

Original `load` is stored as local variable and can't be overwritten for `load_extension` in *following* lua scripts/functions.

If normal user can modify init scripts or can load external libraries (.dll/.so), you're out of luck to properly secure your code.

If the user has access to `resultServerr` content, you're out of luck hiding it, as this variable can be passed to any other process/function, not only `print` or `load`.

Answer (score -2):

Overwrite `print = nil` then it can't print.

You can *create your own hidden print function* if you still need that capability;  just remember what you called it, so you can access it later.

```
hidden_print = print
print = nil

print('this')
```

stdin:1: attempt to call a nil value (global 'print')
stack traceback:
stdin:1: in main chunk
[C]: in ?

```
hidden_print('that')
```

that

Comment: Thanks, but still if someone do on top code load = print he will still get code.
It only works if someone do print below ```print = nil```